# Django tests imports use content type values from real database

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

My application is built on top of Django and DRF. I'm trying to test a serializer with a structure similar to this one:

#### settings.py

```py
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'unbreakablepass',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_db',
        }
    }
}
...
```

#### models.py

```py
class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('name'), max_length=150)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_('order'), default=0)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)

class Task(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
```

#### serializers.py

```py
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['status']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'status': {
                'queryset': Status.objects.filter(
                    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Task)
                )
            }
        }
```

#### tests.py

```py
from myapp.serializers import TaskSerializer
from myapp.models import Task

class TaskTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_content_type(self):
        # Do something with ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Task)
        ...
```

My problem is that since the serializers are imported in `tests.py`, they are imported before the test database is setup when I run `manage.py test --keepdb`. Now, the ContentType value in the `queryset` attribute of my related field, is filtered with `ContentType` values from the main db, not the test db. So my tests would fail if they attempted to use any value in the related field.

The obvious choices seem to be:

- Import the serializer inside the testing code. I really dislike this. Also, many different tests may use the serializer.
- Use some hack in my `settings.py` such as `if 'test' in sys.argv:` and change the DATABASES definition. Kind of like this one better, but still feels too hacky.

Is there any good practice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The age of this question is 3 years, but I faced it today. So I will put here advice how I beat it.

In my problem tests were failing because ContentType was using production DB (django 1.1 don't ask why I work on this version :))

I didn't find any solution better then manipulate settings but there is the way it seems logic for me.

In django ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/advanced/)) there is approach how to start tests from separated script "runtest.py". In this file you can manipulate settings before tests actually will be performed. It's nice to have TEST_RUNNER attribute indicated in settings.py. When you start tests with manage.py test it's 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'.

runtests.py according to documentation with corrections to beat this issue with ContentType could be:

```
import os
import sys

import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.utils import get_runner

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tests.test_settings'
    django.setup()
    
    # We change name of prod database to point on test DB 
    settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"] = \
        'test_' + settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]
    # Because we change prod name on test DB name actually without 
    # same db indicated as test db it will create test_test_<your DB NAME>
    settings.DATABASES["default"]["TEST"]['NAME'] \
        = settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]

    TestRunner = get_runner(settings)
    test_runner = TestRunner()
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(["tests"])
    sys.exit(bool(failures))
```

Maybe there is a better approach, but I couldn't find it. In my problem in the very end of the test, there was the problem in manager where ContentType was used. It tries to connect to production database in the end of the tests.